# How to get N records from numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following two numpy arrays `X` and `y`:

X:

```
array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

y:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Totally, there are `4` unique values in `y`: 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I need to extract `batch_size` records from `X` and `y` in such a way that all unique values are selected in `y` at least once.

For example, if `batch_size` is equal to 6, then the result  of `y` might be:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4  # CORRECT !
```

The corresponding `X` values should be selected.

I have the following function, but it may return `batch_s` that, for example, only contains values 1 and 2, but does not contain 3 and 4:

```
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 # WRONG !
```

My function:

```
def extract_batch_size(myarr, step, batch_size):
    # Function to fetch a "batch_size" amount of data from "myarr" data.

    shape = list(myarr.shape)
    shape[0] = batch_size
    batch_s = np.empty(shape)

    for i in range(batch_size):
        # Loop index
        index = ((step-1)*batch_size + i) % len(myarr)
        batch_s[i] = myarr[index]

    return batch_s
```

This is how I call this function:

```
X_result = extract_batch_size(X, 1, 6)
y_result = extract_batch_size(y, 1, 6)
```

Comment: You want to get algorithm right, or it can be done with some python libs (I would have ```collections.Counter``` in mind)?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski: The problem is that `extract_batch_size` should be applied to `X` and `y`, while the decision should be made based on `y`. Then, the same indices should be retrieved from `X` in order to make pairs of `X` and `y` correct. Therefore, I use `index` inside `extract_batch_size`.

Comment: What means the variable 'step'?

Comment: @TopDeveloper: I use `step` in order to create a sliding window, so that the starting point is the same for `X` and `y`. Then I have a for loop, in which `step` changes, and I can get `X_result` and `y_result` by calling `extract_batch_size`.

Comment: Do you want to choose randomly?

Comment: @TopDeveloper: Yes, please see my comment in the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

def random_choice(arr, elem, max_num):  

    find_indices = list(filter(lambda i: arr[i]==elem, range(len(arr))))
    limit = min(max_num, len(find_indices))
    cnt = np.random.randint(1, limit + 1)
    arr_choice = np.random.choice(find_indices, cnt, replace=False)

    return arr_choice

def extract_batch_size(X, y, batch_size):

    uniq_val = np.unique(y)
    np.random.shuffle(uniq_val)
    uniq_num = len(uniq_val)

    if uniq_num == batch_size:   # too many unique values
        return X, y
    elif uniq_num < batch_size:
        indices = []
        for idx in range(uniq_num):
            cnt = batch_size - len(indices) - uniq_num + idx + 1
            find_indices = random_choice(y, uniq_val[idx], cnt)
            indices.extend(find_indices)
        return X[indices], y[indices]

    return None, None
```

Result:

```
X = np.array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4])

X_result, y_result = extract_batch_size(X, y, 6)
# indices: [17, 16, 15, 11, 6, 8]
# X_result: [1 1 1 3 3 2]
# y_result: [4 4 4 1 3 2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `collections.Counter` you can just do:

```py
from collections import Counter
def extract_batch_size(myarr, batch_size):
    cnt=Counter(myarr)
    if(len(cnt.keys())>len(myarr)): #too many unique values
        return None, None
    elif(len(myarr)<batch_size): #too little array to satisfy requested batch_size
        return None, None
    elif(len(cnt.keys())==batch_size):
        res=list(cnt.keys())
        indices=[myarr.index(el) for el in res]
        return res, indices
    else:
        lst=list(cnt.keys())
        indices=[myarr.index(el) for el in lst]
        for i in cnt:
            if(cnt[i]>1):
                lst=lst+[i]*min(batch_size-len(lst),cnt[i]-1)
            if(len(lst)==batch_size):
                start=len(indices)
                for j in range(start, len(lst)):
                    k=0
                    s=myarr[k:].index(lst[j])
                    while(s in indices):
                        k=s+1
                        s=myarr[k:].index(lst[j])+k
                    indices.append(s)
                return lst, indices
```

Outputs for your use case:

```py
X=[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]

X_result, X_indices= extract_batch_size(X, 6)
>>> X_result
[2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2]

y_result, y_indices = extract_batch_size(y, 6)
>>> y_result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]

#to output from X based on y_result indices:

>>> np.array(X)[y_indices]
[2 1 3 1 1 2]
```

Comment: Thanks. But will I get the same indices for both `X` and `y`? I call `extract_batch_size` for both `X` and `y`. For example, if `extract_batch_size` returns the first record from `y`, then it should also return the first record from `X`. This is the reason why I use `step` in my function.

Comment: Your function looks nice. But I think that the requirement of "same" indices is not met. As I said in my post, the tricky thing is that the condition of all unique values should only be applied to `y`. Then, `X` should be selected with respect to indices of `y`.

Comment: Ah, what if same indices won't do ? Also - you want this to be repeatedly done to many arrays, returning same indices, maybe you should just put all the arrays as an argument of this function and run through them all at once to ensure common indices? Not sure you can do it so it returns same indices regardless of an array

Comment: Yes, actually it's fine if the function `extract_batch_size` is executed once for both `X` and `y`: `extract_batch_size(X, y, batch_size)`. And, yes, it is repeadly executed inside for loop. So, the idea is that each time random pairs of `X_result` and `y_result` are returned, so that `batch_s` includes all possible unique values of `y`.

Comment: Ok, I added some code to return not only numbers, but also indices - now you can get indices from ```y_result``` and pull the numbers accordingly from ```X```